# What is this VBA primitive data type?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to find the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143.

I dimmed a double type in VBA which attached a # sign to the end of the number so I'm thinking this indicates the value exceeds the double type's limitation but I can still run arithmetic with it unless I want to do something like the modulus function. If I run the code below it gives me an overflow error:

```
Sub test()

 Dim x As Double
 x = 600851475143#
 x = x - 1
 x = x Mod 11


End Sub
```

But if I change the code and don't declare my variable and allow VBA to do it the modulus function will work without an overflow. Shown below:

```
Sub test()

 x = 600851475143#
 x = x - 1
 x = x Mod 11

End Sub
```

So in the second set of code, what is the variable type for x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Bluefeet is correct that an undeclared variable defaults to a Variant data type.  **But there is no such internal type as 'Variant'.**  What gets stored internally depends on the value assigned to the variable.  You can inspect how a value is being handled by using the `TypeName()` function:

```
Sub test1()
 Dim x As Variant: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Empty'
            x = 1: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Integer'
        x = 32768: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Long'
        x = 32767: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Integer'
         x = Null: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Null'
          x = 1.1: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Double'
        x = Empty: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Empty'
           x = "": Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'String'
x = 600851475143#: Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Double'
End Sub
```

Copy and paste the above code and execute it and you will see that 'Variant' never gets returned as the name of the type.  The last line is the one that will interest you.

Comment: You're right! That's really weird, the first time I ran the code it worked. Very strange

Comment: darn it, didn't mean to hit enter.. But thank you for the debug tip. I need to get some more information on the debugging side to get used to it. I've been sent to do more extensive VBA projects so I'm already hitting its limitations! Yikes.. But it is what it is, at least it supports classes and interfaces!

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, do you know if there's a data type that will support the very long value 600851475143 properly in VBA or can it not be done?  I know I can solve this in Java but curious about VBA's math limits

Answer (score 2):

You should always declare the data type but if you do not declare the data type then the default is a `Variant`

[VBA Variant](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx)

> Most of the time, you should declare your variables with specific data
>   types, such as String, Long, or Double. VBA supports the Variant data
>   type that can hold any type of data. If you omit the As Type clause in
>   a variable declaration, Variant is the default type. While this may
>   seem useful, it increases processing time when encountered in code
>   because behind the scenes, the compiler has added no small amount of
>   code to test what type of data is actually stored in the variable.
>   Moreover, using a Variant can mask possible Type Mismatch errors that
>   should be caught during testing. Instead of using a Variant type,
>   declare the variable with a specific data type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I usually use option explicit but in this case I was trying to find a data type that supported very large numbers in VBA. Not sure there is one

Comment: *Explicit* and *specific* are different things. `Dim x As Variant` is explicit; it's just not specific.

Comment: ok? But option explicit forces variables to be declared or else the code refuses to run right? So that's kinda what I meant, I'm usually forcing myself to declare variables, also reduces typos and errors in my projects